# Does a mpi request finish if recv and send is matched

Tags: c++, mpi, boost-mpi

Is it enough to check only one request object from two matching non-blocking send and recv operations.

This would be great as this would reduce the effort to handle the request objects in my program.

Here a small example with boost mpi:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // initialize mpi

    mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    boost::mpi::communicator world;
    boost::mpi::request req0, req1;
    double blub;
    if(world.rank()==1)
       req1 = world.irecv(0, 23, blub);
    if(world.rank()==0)
       req0 = world.isend(0, 23, blub);

    //now I want to synchronize the processors is this enough?
    req0.wait();
    //or do I also need this line
    req1.wait();

}
```

Comment: You should really think about which statement gets executed in which process. It's a bit hard for MPI newcommers to grasp this schizophrenic behaviour but in time you'll get used to it. By the way, if you don't care about the outcome of any `I`-operation, you can free the request handle with `MPI_Request_free()` (sorry, don't know what boost MPI's equivalent is) and it will be automatically disposed by the MPI library when it has completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rank 1 doesn't have a valid `req0`, and rank 0 doesn't have a valid `req1`; they are requests which are only valid on the tasks that actually performed the nonblocking operation (and returned a handle to a request).

So no, neither rank here needs to (or even could) call wait on both requests; each calls a wait on the request that it has, eg

```
if(world.rank()==0)
    req0.wait();
if(world.rank()==1)
    req1.wait();
```

or, better (I assume that the isend for rank 0 should go to rank 1, not 0):

```
boost::mpi::request req;
...
if(world.rank()==1)
   req = world.irecv(0, 23, blub);
if(world.rank()==0)
   req = world.isend(1, 23, blub);

if (world.rank() == 0 || world.rank() == 1)
   req.wait();
```

Note that when you *do* need to wait for the multiple operations corresponding to multiple requests, you can have a list of the requests and call [wait_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/wait_all.html).